# preventDefault before AJAX, form still submits with success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a form that requires certain things to be true before submitting. Running into some issues with ajax here..

```
 $('form').submit(function(event){
     form = $(this); // I've tried just: this. Same result
     material = $('#material'). val();
     hours = $('#hours'). val();

     // - Material and Hours are numbers
     if(isNaN(material)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert('Please enter a number for Material');
     }
     if(isNaN(hours)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert('Please enter a number for Hours');
     }


     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url : 'page.php',
         data : {
             'id' : {{ id }}
         },
         type : 'post',
         dataType: "json",
         success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.job_num == {{ job_id }}) {
                form.submit();
            } else {
                alert('Please enter a valid number');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Please enter a valid number');                    
        }
    });

});
```

As you can see, `hours` could be `NaN` and the form will not submit.. but when it gets to the ajax and if it is successful, the form will submit even if `hours` is still `NaN`..

I've tried putting the ajax before the `if` statements, same result.. Not sure if this is something simple that I'm overlooking, or if it's really this complicated..

Comment: Put a `return;` after you error `alert()`

Comment: Of course it was that simple.. Thank you very much! If you want to make it an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `return;` after you error `alert()` and it will end the event function no metter what.

`event.preventDefault()` will prevent the `form` to be submitted, and not the rest of function to be executed, that is why your ajax request keeps being executed.

Comment: @sudo sry, I didn't get it.

Comment: It's OK thank you. I feel like it's a step in the right direction lol

Comment: This was solved by adding:  `form.unbind().submit();` along with returns